# Remove button onclick and add it back after some operation

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove and add back onclick to button so to remove the click event i am using this

```
$(this).prop('onclick', null).off('click');
```

similarly what is the opposite way to add back the click event. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are you using ugly inline click handlers?

Comment: @Satpal can u please suggest any other way to remove and add button click event in jquery.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the event just use .off()

```
$(this).off('click');
```

then you can add the event back like this:

```
$(this).on('click',function() { /* Do stuff */ });
```

Comment: I am getting error ReferenceError: callback is not defined at  

$("#btnsearchfilter").on('click',callback);

Comment: that callback is your function, which executes on click, just updated my answer, check

Answer (score 1):

use this to remove onclick or click event

```
$(this).removeAttr("onclick");
```

use this to Add onclick or click event

```
$(this).attr("onclick","");
```